# HttpClient missing last byte in response.content

Tags: c#, android, http, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms App which should communicate with an embedded device via a RESTService. 
So in my SharedProject I have a Service which wraps a httpclient.

```cs
HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 31) };
public async Task<MetaData> RequesMetaData()
        {
            try
            {


                var response =await client.GetAsync("http://192.168.1.23:9090/api/meta/", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var result =  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var meta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MetaData>(result);
                return meta;
            }
            catch(OperationCanceledException ocex)
            {

                ConnectionError?.Invoke(new Message { MessageInfo = ocex.Message, IsError = true });
                return new MetaData();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ConnectionError?.Invoke(new Message { MessageInfo = ex.Message, IsError = true });
                Debug.Print(ex.GetType().Name);
                return new MetaData();
            }
        }
```

The call should return a Json, which works most times.
The problem is sometimes, the last byte, the curly bracket '}' of the Json is missing.
It is always the last '}', no matter how long the message sent by the server was.

This only occurs on Android. When I test the RESTservice from Firefox, 
no such error occurs. Additionally I logged with Wireshark, which reports the full json was delivered over the wire. 
Also I tried the same code in a WPF Desktop App, which works flawless. Only on Xamarin Android it is missing the last byte. In the Android Options, 
I tried all options (Android,Managed,Default).
Instead of ReadAsStringAsync(), I also tried ReasAsStreamAsync(), but got the same results.

When changing to https, this issue persits but in another form. Instead of the missing last byte, on occassion the Content will just be an empty string "", 
maybe because the message could not be decrypted.

For testing I use the x86 Emulator of VisualStudio(Android 9) , as well as a Nexus 5 (Android 6).

Comment: Does it occur if you use `ReadAsStreamAsync` and then read the stream with `StreamReader`? I'm wondering if it's some kind of bug in whatever translation layer exists (I'm not really familiar with how Xamarin works).

Comment: Yes, I also tried ReadAsStreamAsync+ StreamReader, the result is the same, last byte is missing.

Comment: @SigiN,By I search, many articles suggest to use ReadAsStreamAsync and streamReader to get data from json, thereis no issue about this:https://johnthiriet.com/efficient-api-calls/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue. 
The server of the embedded device I was talking to was using http/1.0 and didn't include content-length. Changing it to use http/1.1 and using content-lenght solved the issue for me. 
I can only guess that Xamarin.Android  HttpClient has problems with http/1.0.